# No module named 'MySQLdb'?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to run a script and the second line is:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snp500.py", line 2, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as mdb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I had the same problem with importing bs4, however I was able to solve it by installing bs4 with pipenv. The same does not work for MySQLdb. What do I do? What could be causing this?
I have tried `pip3 install mysqlclient` and i get error:

```
    OSError: mysql_config not found
----------------------------------------

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: I believe MySQLdb  only supports Python 2

Comment: Install the `mysqlclient` package; it's the modern drop-in replacement for `MySQLdb`.

Comment: Assuming you are using pip for package managing, does `pip list | grep MySQLDB` output anything? If no, that means you don't have a package with this name installed.

Comment: I am using pip3. When I try `pipe3 install mysqlclient`, i get error: `OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

Comment: so it is not letting me install mysqlclient for some reason